# Is there a way to restrict Picture-in-picture to only work within an application and not persist when backgrounded?

Tags: android, exoplayer, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

Is there any way to allow PiP functionality only while the user is within an application?

Ideally, the user can launch PiP, but when they background the app the PiP would dismiss and background playback would continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to achieve this is by using the `onUserLeaveHint()` callback from the Framework.

The example given by the documentation is the *opposite* of what you're trying to do, but just *flip the boolean*. ;)

> You might want to include logic that switches an activty into PIP mode instead of going into the background. For example, Google Maps switches to PIP mode if the user presses the home or recents button while the app is navigating. You can catch this case by overriding onUserLeaveHint():

source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

```
@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint () {
    if (iWantToBeInPipModeNow()) {
        enterPictureInPictureMode();
    }
}
```

What the method `iWantToBeInPipModeNow()` does is really up-2-you, but you could intercept that, and exit PiP (if you are in it).

You can also ensure your back/stop methods also ensure PiP is handled appropriately for your use case.

Comment: Do you have a code example for programmatically exiting from PIP mode as you mention you could do? I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: Uhh hmmm I have not used PiP since 2019... but [here is a question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388320/how-to-close-picture-in-picture-programmatically) combo that talks about that.