# How to close Picture in Picture programmatically

Tags: android, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I have this problem with Picture in Picture mode that i want to close the PIP (Picture in Picture) when the activity is opened again from somewhere other than the PIP itself. Not from the close button.

I want the same scenario that youtube has i.e. when user clicks the PIP (Picture in Picture) it opens the same activity but when user selects another video form the list it ends the previous PIP (Picture in Picture) and opens a new activity. In my case when i open a new video it resumes the video i was previously playing.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible ways to do this:

1. If you have activity access then move the activity to the back.

   ```
   activity.moveTaskToBack(false);
   ```

[From Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack(boolean))

> Move the task containing this activity to the back of the activity
>   stack. The activity's order within the task is unchanged.

2. You can restore the activity to the front

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(PipScreenActivity.this, PipScreenActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
   activity.startActivity(intent);
   ```

Comment: I don't want to come back to the same activity. This resumes the activity

Comment: @HuzaifaAsif Official Documentation says, "If another video starts playing on the main screen, the PIP window is automatically closed."

Comment: I'm not sure about this as it is not closing in my case. I actually have a TV app. When i get in PIP mode and open another channel, the previous channel keeps playing in PIP.

Comment: @HuzaifaAsif Are you using same activity?

Comment: Yes. I'm opening the same activity.

Comment: @HuzaifaAsif If you go with the second approach as given in the answer, then in `onResume` method you can change the video source to the new source

Comment: Well let me try the on resume!

Comment: @HuzaifaAsif Have you check?

Comment: Yes. But it didn't work for me. It does open a new video but it does not close the previously running picture in picture

Comment: @HuzaifaAsif Can you post the code? How you are opening a PIP window.

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to resolve this issue? @HuzaifaAsif

Comment: Nope i didn't get any proper solution so i followed the mechanism used by youtube.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity A**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("finish_activity");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Activity B**

```
 BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("finish_activity")) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("finish_activity"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!AppPreferences.getIsSameCinema(this).equals(idtitle)){//check is this a new film or no
        idtitle = AppPreferences.getIsSameCinema(this);
        streamLink = AppPreferences.getLinkCinema(this);
        stopPlayer();
        startPlayer(); //full player start
    } else{
        resumePlayer(); //prepare and setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
}
```

`idtitle` and `streamLink` - extras for current player intent

`idtitle` - UUID, `streamLink` - video url

Change SharedPreferences when player activity starts.